# makefile: search for files in subdirectories

Tags: makefile

So I have a GCC command for which I want to use a SIMPLE makefile. Never worked on makefile before and still having problems after referring the tutorial.

So the command on terminal is

```
link4@link4-VirtualBox:~/link4/G2/G2 module/src$ gcc -I.src/L4COMM -I.src/L4SERIAL -I.src/L4SYSTEM -I.src/main.c -I.src/L4COMM/l4comm.c -I.src/L4SERIAL/l4serial.c ./src/bypass.c ./src/input.c
```

This works fine, but when I create a makefile, I'm unable to make it search for the files 'l4comm.c and l4serial.c' which are in src/L4COMM and src/L4SERIAL respectively.

This is what my makefile looks like:

```
CC =gcc
INCLUDE = -I/src/L4COMM \
          -I/src/L4SERIAL
VPATH = -I/src/L4COMM \
        -I/src/L4SERIAL

cfiles := $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(wildcard *.c))
hfiles := $(patsubst %.h, %.o, $(wildcard *.h))

g2make: $(cfiles)
        $(CC) $(INCLUDE) -o main.c l4comm.c l4serial.c bypass.c input.c
```

1. Want the makefile to look for files in the sub directories
2. Just as I used the 'cfiles/hfiles' to check for changes, I want to wildcard to also check for the files in the sub directories.

Help appreciated! :)

Comment: If there are only two files to find, and you know where they are, do you really need a full-powered search?

Comment: Try `VPATH = ./src/L4COMM ./src/L4SERIAL`

Comment: Automatically including any source files in your tree in a build??? **UGH!!!**. Be explicit in make. (Though you can do what you ask with `cfiles := $(shell find . -type f -name '*.c')`.)

Answer (score -1):

You can use this g2make:

```
 $(CC) $(INCLUDE) -o .src/main.c ./src/L4COMM/l4comm.c ./src/L4SERIAL/l4serial.c ./src/bypass.c ./src/input.c
```